# Use variable from object in module with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In object -Sheet2- I've this:

```
Private Sub Listbox1_Change()
    keuze = Sheet2.Listbox1.Text
End Sub
```

I want to use the variable keuze in a module, but what I try, it's empty. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Declare `keuze` in module as

```
Public keuze As String
```

Then after assigning `keuze = Sheet2.Listbox1.Text` you can access value of `keuze` in module also.

By using the `Public` keyword, variable will be available across all modules and the value of `Public` variable will preserve until Workbook is closed or reset the Project.